# Binding jQuery event handler to `focus` makes select behave strange in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Why does this below jQuery binding of an eventhandler to the `focus` event have the side-effect that the user needs to click twice on the select-option do make it drop down/up.

```
$('input, select, textarea').focus(function() {
  $(this).addClass('input_highlight');
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('input_highlight');
});
```

This is only an issue for IE (tested in IE8), Chrome and FF behaves as expected.

My testcase, including all relevant css, can be seen here: [jsFiddle sandbox example](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/F3cBk/6/)

Comment: Hmm, my best guess is that because the browser has to re-evaluate the css when a class has been added to an element, the element has efectively been changed and so requires a second click to re-select this 'new' element. -- Can you not just add the necessary styles directly with jquery, or use the .highlight() function?

Comment: In my test even using .css will require a 2nd click and highlight has a similar bug. The select drops down then disappears each time you click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to use focusin and focusout instead of focus and blur.

http://jsfiddle.net/QG22b/

Answer (score 0):

The .focus event is activated on IE only when you click on it (and not when your mouse comes over it).

Maybe you could use the [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event ?

Max

Comment: Thanks for your input - the focusin/focusout as suggested by Ryan seemed easier though